# A way to share common template HTML and JavaScript behavior across AngularJS directives?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building a form builder AngularJS app, and I have the following AngularJS directive representing the UI to edit a TextField:

```
angular.module('myApp.directives').directive('textFormFieldElement', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
    'use strict';

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            element: '='
        },
        template: '<div class="form-element text-form-field">' +
                  '    <span class="identifier">TF</span>' +
                  '    <strong class="heading" ng-bind="headingText()"></strong>' +
                  '    <div class="editor">' +
                  '        <div class="form-group">' +
                  '            <label>Enter the field name:</label>' +
                  '            <input ng-model="element.fieldName" type="text" class="form-control" />' +
                  '        </div>' +
                  '        <div class="form-group">' +
                  '            <label>Enter a label for the field:</label>' +
                  '            <input ng-model="element.label" type="text" class="form-control" />' +
                  '        </div>' +
                  '        <div class="form-group">' +
                  '            <label>Enter a note for the field:</label>' +
                  '            <input ng-model="element.note" type="text" class="form-control" />' +
                  '        </div>' +
                  '        <div class="checkbox">' +
                  '            <label>' +
                  '                <input ng-model="element.required" type="checkbox" /> Required' +
                  '            </label>' +
                  '        </div>' +
                  '    </div>' +
                  '</div>',

        link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
            scope.element.fieldName = scope.element.fieldName || 'TextField';

            // Expand the editor when creating new elements, and focus on the first field once rendered.
            if (!scope.element._id) {
                $timeout(function() {
                    element.find('.editor').addClass('expanded');
                    element.find('.editor').find('input:first').select();
                }, 10);
            }

            scope.headingText = function() {
                if (scope.element.fieldName.length && scope.element.fieldName.length > 0) {
                    return scope.element.fieldName;
                }

                return 'TextField';
            };
        }
    };
}]);
```

I also have other controls, like a PhoneField, an EmailField, and a RadioButtonListField.

These directives will often have common HTML in their templates as well as common JavaScript behavior. I'd like a way to share this across directives, without polluting the global namespace.

What are some ways this can be achieved?

Comment: Templates can be also passed in with templateUrl, meaning that one template an be used any amount of times, services seem like a good choice for sharing javascript code.

Comment: True, but would I need to reuse the same template across directives? The key is that each template may have slight variations.

Comment: I'm curious if you've come up with an elegant solution to this problem.  I have very similar needs.

Comment: Well, the need hasn't arisen often, honestly. The only way I have found to share HTML is to use Browserify with the plugins like [stringify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stringify) and [require-globify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-globify) that lets you pull in HTML using `require()`. As for sharing common JavaScript functionality, I would suggest looking at using services. I would be careful to not name the services too generally and cram too much into one service. I would also be careful about sharing data between services, as services are only initialized once per app load.

Answer (score 1):

For template sharing you could extract common template code into 'template directives', i.e. directives that only define template without behavior. This way you can re-use these template directives inside the templates of other directives.

For sharing common JavaScript behavior the two recommended ways are either via Angular services (service/factory) or in the case of directives using directive controller.

For the latter, see the `Creating Directives that Communicate` section at http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive on how to implement this.